# ScrollView takes all space vertically

Tags: android

I use this LinearLayout to make dialog which has Header, list of checkboxes and bottom Buttons. A number of CheckBoxes requires ScrollView. Unfortunately ScrollView takes all space and I'm not able to see buttons section.

Is any solution to get last LinearLayout to be visible if I get huge list?
Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:lht="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/header_text" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Checkbox ....>
                <Checkbox ....>
                <Checkbox ....>
                <Checkbox ....>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button ....>
        <Button ....>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be in the LinearLayout right below the TextView:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
```

You've set the height to "wrap_content". Try to make it "0dp" and then the weight to "1":

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
```

Comment: That is solution. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad to help!